# Loading a photo taken from UIImagePickerController camera asynchronously

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uiimagepickercontroller, alassetslibrary

Initially, I thought I could use `UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL` to obtain the `ALAsset`, then use that to generate an `aspectRatioThumbnail` and load the `ALAsset` asynchronously using GCD. However it appears that taking a photo from the `UIImagePickerController` doesn't produce an `ALAsset` as it's not stored in the photo library, only in memory.

I'd still like to somehow produce an `ALAsset` so I can access the `aspectRatioThumbnail` and load it the same way I am with the `UIImagePickterController` photo library. Is it possible to do this without saving the photo to the photo library?

Otherwise is there any other good ways to accomplish this outside of using `ALAsset`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how to do it, doesn't really make sense to make a thumbnail because it'll prob cost too much in performance to do it:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    self.photoImageView.image = nil;
    [self.activityIndicatorView startAnimating];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0), ^
    {
        UIImage *image = [[info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"] retain];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
        {
            self.photoImageView.image = image;
            [self.activityIndicatorView stopAnimating];
            [image release];
        });

    });
}
```